# Does ubuntu run on any other devices besides pc's?

Tags: devices

Does ubuntu run on any other devices besides personal computers?

Comment: ehm, what are you thinking of?

Comment: Ofcourse... I have it running on servers, laptops, notebooks, a tablet and a phone. This does not seem like a problem with Ubuntu to me.

Comment: It is also able to run on a Television but hasn't been officially released to the public and isn't currently in commercial use also.

Comment: It also runs on phones, tablets and chromebooks (ARM processors). See the top orange bar http://www.ubuntu.com/

Comment: What do you mean by “personal computers”? There's a narrow meaning that denotes all IBM-compatible computers, nowadays called x86 architecture and the derived AMD64 architecture, and a broad meaning denoting all computers designed for personal usage and general purpose computing tasks.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu for tablets and smartphones is in development.You can already try to use them if you feel adventurous.There is also Ubuntu for netbooks.

However Ubuntu is a version of GNU/Linux.And there are versions of Linux that run on devices ranging from microwaves up to supercomputers.There are cars with Linux.Android is also a version of Linux.

With enough knowledge and tweaking you could run Ubuntu on anything with sufficient processing power.

Comment: Don't forget Ubuntu TV.

Comment: Ofcourse...And let's not forget specialised Ubuntu versions like edubuntu etc...

Comment: Does it exist? Does it have at least a 32-bit processor? If so, it can run Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I run [Ubuntu on my BeagleBone Black](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:Ubuntu_On_BeagleBone_Black).

I hear that other people run [Ubuntu on Gumstix](http://wiki.gumstix.org/index.php?title=Category:How_to_-_Ubuntu).